# How to achieve Rails close button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm would like to have a close button on my rails application messages.

[image: close button]

I've read about integrating rails flash messages with twitter bootstrap, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Please post questions meaningfully. Other persons should have to understand what you are looking to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of messages are [bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts). Check the bootstrap documentation, and in rails make sure you have your app integrated with boottrap.

In order to integrate the flash messages with bootstrap I'll suggest you to follow [this approach](https://gist.github.com/roberto/3344628):

create a partial `_flash_messages.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then in your `application.html.erb` add:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/flash_messages", flash: flash %>
```

in your `application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    case flash_type
      when :success
        "alert-success"
      when :error
        "alert-error"
      when :alert
        "alert-block"
      when :notice
        "alert-info"
      else
        flash_type.to_s
    end
  end

end
```